# NULL == nullptr в C++11?

Tags: c++11

NULL == nullptr в C++11?

Comment: не совcем.  NULL большинством компиляторов с легкостью трактуется как 0 (на самом деле это обычно define). Но нет 100 гарантии, что это так. А вот nullptr - это известная для компилятора константа и компилятор знает, что это такое.

Comment: @KoVadim, можно сказать, что надежнее будет инициализировать указатели nullptr, для дальнейшей проверки на корректность, нежели NULL?

Comment: nullptr как раз специально ввели, что бы решить часть неоднозначных ситуаций с NULL.

Это все лучше утрясется в голове, если понимать, то компилятор не видет NULL, он видит обычно вместо него 0 (препроцессор постарался). А вот nullptr виден. И компилятор может сделать анализ.

Comment: @SoloMio, не совсем. Везде где идет речь про указатели НУЖНО использовать null_ptr. Это гарантия того, что компилятор попробует застраховать программиста от ошибки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот вам пример, когда `nullptr` *лучше*, чем `NULL`:

```
void f(int) { cout << "f(int)" << endl; }
void f(char*) { cout << "f(char*)" << endl; }

char* s = NULL;
f(s);        // f(char*)
f(NULL);     // f(int)
f(nullptr);  // f(char*)
```

http://ideone.com/P7JAIg

Answer (score 4):

Вообще говоря, выражение `NULL == nullptr` всегда истино, это гарантирует стандарт:

> Two operands of type `std::nullptr_t` or
> one operand of type `std::nullptr_t` and
> the other a null pointer constant
> compare equal.

Но, как вам уже написали, NULL это не то же самое, что nullptr.